# Prevent keyboard from dismissing while pushing view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikeyboard

I am having a hard time controlling keyboard behavior when I push a `UIViewController` using `pushViewController:animated:` The from view contains some `UITextField`s but the to view has none. If the keyboard is present at the time of the push, it self-resigns automatically alongside the horizontal push animation. It's a little jarring to see the from view slide down at the same time as the to view slides in.

Can I have the keyboard maintain its position and slide horizontally out of view with the from controller? I've certainly seen this done the other way round, where the to controller has a presented keyboard sliding in from the left when pushed.

Comment: Normally it's the other way round. People want to dismiss the keyboard before push animation. If you wish to keep the push animation, it's quite hard to achieve your goal, as it's the default behavior of the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I, too, am not sure this is possible.  Basically you have to add the keyboard as a subview of the current view in `prepareForSegue`.  I don't know if you can do that with the keyboard.

If not, you can sorta cheat by doing the following in `prepareForSegue`:

1. Taking a screen shot of the portion of the view containing the keyboard
2. Add the screen shot to the view as a subview
3. Dismiss the keyboard without animation

Answer (score -4):

Its very simple to handle keyboard when you are navigating from one screen to another screen by the help of push the where you are putting the code of pushing on the same place you can use--
  [Textfield Resignfirstresponder];
This will handle automatic your keyboard. hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: I am looking for the opposite - to prevent this.